# vscode with java: how to suppress warning by line

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Although there are many questions and answers on disabling warnings in vscode used as a java ide,
I did not find anything to suppress a warning punctually at a given line.
I think of a feature like PMD which uses some comment to that end.

Comment: Can @SuppressWarnings("all")  meet your needs?